# In c++ why is pass by reference is directed by callee rather than by caller

Tags: c++

In c++, the function signature defines that it will take the arguments by reference or value. Isn’t it the caller should decide what it wants to pass by reference or value?
Suppose caller does not want the function to modify its values, and is unsure of what the calle is doing inside its function. Then the caller does not have a right to say that the arguments should not be modified.

How is this C++ definiton justified?

Comment: Don't call the function then? How is this different from passing by pointer? Same problem.

Comment: Use a `const &` if you don't modify

Comment: If the parameter is passed by const reference it can't be modified.  If passed by reference and the caller wants to ensure that the value is not modified, the caller can pass a copy.

Comment: In my car pressing right pedal causes acceleration. Why is the meaning of the right pedal is defined by the car manufacturer and not the driver? What if I don't want the car to accelerate?

Comment: In other languages, you don't even have a choice. E.g. In Java, there is no way the caller can tell the function that it shouldn't modify the value.

Comment: @king_nak well, you can make a co... I mean, implement the Clone pattern ;)

Comment: I really don't like the condescending tone in these comments. I find the question to be legitimate. If I have `int i; func(i);` in C I know for a fact that my variable will not change its value, irreverent of the declaration of `func`, because I didn't supply the necessary information to do this to `func`. This is not true in C++ and may be confusing. It feels like the caller somehow looses some control. To request the official justification for this is very reasonable, I think.

Comment: @Nils_M Yes this exactly what i thought too. Its a legitimate question and any one who worked on large projects which have multiple library modules developed by different groups will know this. Also most other languages require you to add & to variables at the caller if the function is modified to take references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call-by-reference vs. call-by-value isn't primarily about "modification" vs. "read-only". `const` is for indicating if a parameter is read-only or not. The choice of call-by-reference vs. call-by-value in function design is more often about the performance impacts.

For example, an `int` is usually passed-in-register while a `int *` would pass the pointer in-register but require a dereference to access. This is most obvious in structures/classes where passing-by-value will involve copying chunks of memory larger than a machine word and/or calling constructors/destructors on temporaries.

For example, this function requires temporary generation, a ctor/dotr cycle, possibly with heap allocation on every call invocation:

```
void foo(const std::string s);
```

While this one avoids additional temporaries while still being read-only:

```
void foo(const std::string& s);
```

The design choices of how the function takes parameters is explicitly visible to the caller so that the developer can in turn make their own performance-related tradeoffs in how it's used. C/C++ code performance is in large part based on putting data in the right place, and passing references to it in the right way.

> As for "how is this justified in C++" questions, see Stroustrup, "The Design and Evolution of C++", Addison-Wesley (1994)

Answer (score 0):

It is done this way to make overloading more versatile, and because the interpreter decides which function to call based off what parameters you pass.  Say I have two functions

```
void add(int* a, int* b){
    *a= *a+*b;
    *b = *a;
}
```

and

```
int add(const& int a, const& int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

These are two very different ways of adding two numbers.  When I call these functions the interpreter knows which one to call based off what I pass it.

Answer (score 0):

It's always caller who "decide" what callee to call based on types of arguments. There are strict resolution rules which are pretty reasonable. Search for C++ overload resolution. E.g.: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution.

Different overloads are different functions with same name in source code they have different mangled name but not in object files.